# Type of predictors for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

Can predictors in logistic regression be categorical, numerical and ordinal?

If categorical, can they be trichotomous?

Comment: Yes. Long answer to meet the requirement of 15 letters: why not?

Comment: Yes, it can. But You have to make dummy variables for every level (minus 1) of ordinal vars.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is the same as for ordinary linear regression. Namely, the model allows you to posit a linear relationship between an IV and the (log odds of the) DV, which is appropriate for many numerical predictors, and also suffices for categorical predictors on a nominal scale if you code each predictor into *k* - 1 dummy variables where *k* is the number of levels (don't forget to include an intercept term). The ordinal case is more difficult, because inserting an ordinal predictor as a single model term treats the differences between levels as equal, and dummy-coding an ordinal predictor makes the order information unavailable to the model. If you need more sophistication than either of those methods, you'll need a fancier model. Here's an article that discusses the question of what to do with one kind of ordinal predictor, rating scales:

Tutz, G., & Gertheiss, J. (2014). Rating scales as predictors—The old question of scale level and some answers. *Psychometrika, 79*, 357–376. doi:10.1007/s11336-013-9343-3